# How to preventing Overwriting of Redis GameStatus during User Modification and Broadcasting using Pub/Sub in NodeJS Game Server

Tags: node.js, caching, redis, socket.io, publish-subscribe

I am trying to create a game server using NodeJS and Redis. I am using one GameStatus in Redis to perform broadcasting to the corresponding clients using Pub/Sub.

The problem is that I cannot guarantee integrity when each user modifies the GameStatus and receives broadcasting using Pub/Sub. For example, User 1 reads the GameStatus and modifies it at 0.1 seconds, and at the same time, User 2 reads the GameStatus at 0.2 seconds.

At 0.3 seconds, User 1 stores the modified GameStatus information in Redis, but until then, User 2 continues to modify the GameStatus. At 0.4 seconds, when User 2 saves the GameStatus, the information modified by User 1 is overwritten.

Is there a way to prevent such overwriting?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Redis supports couple of way to ensure atomicity.

1. Transactions see: https://redis.io/docs/manual/transactions/
2. Lua script see: https://redis.io/docs/manual/programmability/eval-intro/